# El controller de laravel no reconoce los inputs dinámicos de un form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo una función la cual crea inputs dinámicos con diferentes nombres, un ejemplo sería el input precio-1 y precio-2 el input precio-1 **NO** es dinámico, el input precio-2 **SI** que seria dinámico la cosa es que el form  lo paso via ajax al controller, pero no consigo que el input dinámico (precio-2) me lo reconozca el controller, es como si no existiera.

**Form HTML**

```
  <form id="form_albaran_entrada"  method="get" action="{{route('albaran_entrada_create')}}">
   <input class="form-control widthInput2 precio"  id="precio-{{$num}}" name="precio-{{$num}}" type="number" value="0">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Crear Albaran entrada">
  </form>
```

**Ajax**

```
        $("#create_albaran_entrada").click(function(){
            console.log('entra');
            var url ="{!!route('albaran_entrada_create')!!}";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url, // This is what I have updated
                data: $("#form_albaran_entrada").serialize(),
                success:function(data) {
                    
                    alert('funciona');
                    //$('#etiquetas_elegidas').html('<span style="background:#C0C0C0;font-size:17px;color:white;padding:4px;border-radius:4px;">#Etiquetas elegidas:</span><br>' + '<div style="margin-top:20px !important;font-weight:bold;">' + data + '</div>');
                    //$("#etiquetas-modal").modal('hide');
                    //$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    //$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                    
                    
                
                }
            })


        });
```

**Controller laravel**

```
    public function albaran_entrada_create(Request $request){

    $precio="precio-1";
    $precioB="precio-2"; // no reconoce el input dinamico
    
    $precio1=$request->$precioB;
    
    Log::info($precio1); 
  
 
}
```

**PD: No he puesto el script de la clonacion ya que funciona correctamente**

Comment: Revisa en la pestaña Network de tu navegador si estas enviando los datos correctos, por otra parte, utiliza {} para declarar un objeto dinámico o utiliza helpers del request, ya sea `$request->{$precioB}` o bien, `$request->get($precioB)`

Comment: Colocale un "/" al inicio de tu url a ver.

Comment: Tal vez no te parezca necesario mostrar lo que crees que sí funciona. Pero esa es probablemente la causa del problema. No compartas el loop, vale, pero como estás seguro de que los input se crean dentro del form?